# Prevent selecting column if other row has value in MySQL and CodeIgniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

```
+------+------+
| col1 | col2 |
+------+------+
|    1 |    0 |
|    1 |    3 |
|    1 |    2 |
+------+------+
```

How can I prevent mysql from returning any row with `col1 = 1` when its `col2` has `0` even in other rows? So in this case, I don't want to get any row because first row has `col2 = 0`.

**EDIT**

If this is in the first row 
`col1 = 1 AND col2 = 1`
instead of 
 `col1 = 1 AND col2 = 0`

Then the result should be *the three rows*
Or else there should be *no results*

Comment: So is the question you'd ask the database be along the lines of "Give me all the rows where Col2 is not = 0" ? or is it the same case if col1 is 0 and col2 has a value >0 ?

Comment: No i mean, return `col1` where `col1` = 1, but do not return any if there is a row in table where "`col1` = 1 && `col2` = 0"..

Comment: If the first row, the column 2 is not 0. then my query should return the three row.. However, if any of the three rows has column 2 with 0 value, then, do not return any at all.. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
 $array = array('col1' => '1','col2 !=' => '0');
    $this->db->select('col1,col2');
    $this->db->from('table');
    $this->db->where($array);
    $query = $this->db->get();
```

I think this would work for you..

or else if you want all row with col2!=0 then change array to

```
$array = array('col2 !=' => '0');
```

or you can do it simply mysql way as @Shihas suggested following way

```
$where = "col1='1' AND col2!='0'";
$this->db->where($where);
```

Hope this helps.

Revised my answer as per your requirement..

```
    $sql = mysqli_query($this->db,"SELECT col1,col2 from table where col2=0") or die(mysqli_error($db));

                    if(mysqli_num_rows($sql)>0){
                            $error = array("status"=>"Failed","msg"=>"There is data exist with col2 as 0");
                            $this->response($this->json($error),400);
                    }
                    else{
//put your condition here
                         $sql = mysqli_query($this->db,"SELECT col1,col2 from table where col1=1 col2!=0") or die(mysqli_error($db));

                    }
```

you can put your query in else part,whatever you want to get executed

Comment: Sorry but I cannot mark this as the correct answer too. This code will still return the remain two rows which I do not want.. If you may still want to help, please read the comments on @Shihas answer. Thank you..

Comment: @Jin I've revised my answer take a look,is that what you want.

Comment: Sir, in your else part, your query still returns the two remaining rows. I believe It will still return the two even if the error will be returned on the first row.. But another thank you for revising your answer..

Comment: so you want to return only 1 row if col1=1 & col2=1 or only one row as a resulr @Jin

Comment: As per your first requirement it wouldn't let return any result if any col2 record has 0 value and that's what you wanted right? @Jin

Comment: I am thinking of creating two queries.
`SELECT 'col1' WHERE 'col2' = 0`
And then
`SELECT * WHERE 'col1' NOT IN (first query)`, however, I am bothered with how large the data will be compared. I am worried with the performance.. If the first query returns thousands of data, I don't it is still practical..

Comment: @Jin that's what i did, now all you have to do is refining else part as per your need. whichever way you want & that will work for you Good luck

Comment: Sorry sir but I believe the variable `$sql` on the else part will still contain the two columns.. Maybe I'll just think of another way. But thank you so much for your answer.

Comment: @Jin just tell me what you want in else part to happen & i'll try to refine it if possible

Comment: Sir, I think it's from you query not from the else part.. having a simple query with the condition `col1 = 1 AND col2 = 0` will still not prevent the query from returning the 2 last rows.. What I wanted with your `$sql` variable was to have a value of empty array, null, or false value.. (with just one single query if possible)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have discovered the answer to my own question. The trick is to use the `group by` and `having` clause

`SELECT col1 FROM table WHERE col1 = 1 GROUP BY col2 HAVING col2 != 0`

Thank you very much for those who tried to answer.